# SQL, JAVA Remove Duplicate Strings from SQL output, Array Sort

Tags: java, sql, arrays, sorting, duplicates

I'm accessing an SQL database and I want to retrieve all serial numbers in a column, my problem is not here, my problem is that the sql statement brings all serial numbers whether its duplicate or not.

Here is my SQL Statement;

```
String sqlS = "Select (SerialNumber) from dbo.Results where ErrorCode != 0 AND LineNumber = 1 AND TMDT BETWEEN '" +ourJavaDateObject + "' AND '" + tomorrow + "'";
```

Here is the output:

```
16110201009
16110201014
16110201017
16110201048
16110201048
16110201048
16110201048
16110201048
16110201048
```

Please notice that there are 6 of the same serial number, how can I sort that to delete the serial number.

This is the output that I would like:

```
16110201009
16110201014
16110201017
16110201048
```

Comment: use DISTINCT keyword. Go to this link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-distinct-keyword.htm

Comment: `Select distinct SerialNumber from dbo.Results ...` (unrelated, but: putting a column or a list of columns between parentheses is totally useless)

Comment: Also: please stop concatenating values into a SQL string. Use a `PreparedStatement` with placeholders

Comment: I used distinct and it works, your solution works, Thank you so much.

Comment: @aridi look like you didn't read database before working on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get unique values you need to use the keyword `DISTINCT`.

```
String sqlS = "SELECT DISTINCT (SerialNumber) FROM dbo.Results WHERE ErrorCode != 0 AND LineNumber = 1 AND TMDT BETWEEN '" +ourJavaDateObject + "' AND '" + tomorrow + "'";
```

However your code is not safe against [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), because you parse arguments directly. Would you think of using `PreparedStatement`?

Answer (score 1):

```
"Select distinct (SerialNumber) from dbo.Results where ErrorCode != 0 AND LineNumber = 1 AND TMDT BETWEEN '" + ourJavaDateObject + "' AND '" + tomorrow + "'"
```

Comment: Answer without explanation are not answers.